# How to get rid of iOS 11 Safari <video> overlay

Tags: javascript, ios, css, html5-video

I'm trying to get rid of this `<video>` overlay that occurs in iOS11. I can easily inspect the element and do `display: none` on a child in the shadow DOM, `<div id="media-controls-container">`. However, I can't access this is in neither JavaScript nor CSS, as it is a closed shadowRoot, since it's created by the user-agent. Any solution is welcomed, whether it be Swift/Objective C or CSS/Javascript.

[image]

Comment: See if any of these webkit video CSS pseudo-elements help: https://gist.github.com/webtobesocial/aefd6e25064c08e0cc9a#video

Comment: I already added the entire list and none of them worked. I also checked myself in the shadow DOM, so I know that unfortunately it's not a psuedo-element causing the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is very simple actually. You need to make the video inline, so the native video controls don't show. All you need to do is this: `<video playsinline>`. If you are using Cordova, then you'll have to add `<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />` to your config.xml file.